# How can I fix this error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'backdrop') at _Modal._initializeBackDrop?

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-5

I'm creating a website that is similar to Instagram. While trying to create a modal showing a post by clicking on the image of that post, the console logged out this message:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading
> 'backdrop') at _Modal._initializeBackDrop (modal.js:158:39) at new
> _Modal (modal.js:69:27) at _Modal.getOrCreateInstance (base-component.js:65:41) at HTMLImageElement.
> (modal.js:363:22) at HTMLDocument.handler (event-handler.js:118:19)

Here is my  tag:

```
<a  id="myLink" href="/p/{{ $post->id }} "><img src="/storage/{{ $post->image }}" alt=""
data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModal" class=" me-1" 
style="border-collapse: separate; height: 320px; width: 320px; object-fit: cover"></a>
```

The opening div of the modal:

```
<div class="modal" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
```

The script I'm using to show the modal when clicking on the href:

```
$('a#myLink').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#exampleModal').modal('show').find('.modal-body').load($(this).attr('href'));
    console.log($(this).attr('href'));
});
```

The log does return the href, but the modal isn't showing.

I have read some posts on Laracast and GitHub that have the related error. After conducting my research, I think the problem is my Javascript code, but I couldn't solve it since I have limited experience with Javascript and Jquery.

Comment: Do you want to load the `a#href` or the `img-src` into the modal body?

Comment: I want to pass the post id from the href. Since every images in the user's profile are a post of their own, I have to use id to get the correct image